# UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend error (not specify any in UIBackgroundModes )

Tags: ios

Look, i have this error

[image]

I understand that I need to turn off UIBackgroundModes. But in plist in  UIBackgroundModes i can't establish 'No' on this item. What do I need to install in UIBackgroundModes that would get rid of this error?

PS My plist file

[image]

Comment: Delete the whole `UIBackgroundModes` array. Better yet, go to the Capabilities tab for your target in Xcode and turn off Background Modes.

Comment: @rmaddy  location  will work if I remove the UIBackgroundModes?

Comment: No. You have to remove all background modes which means your app can't use location in the background. Only while the user is using your app. Or you could keep the background modes and turn off the "exit on suspend".

Comment: @rmaddy No, I mean if I location disabled in Capabilities,  when the application is open will work a lokation?